# How would I securely prevent a user from getting a string in my script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I was to give a python script to someone to run, they would have to run it with an API key to allow access to the server. Is there any way I can prevent them from seeing the key but still be able to use it.

Comment: Store the key as an external file on a remote location and have your script fetch it?

Comment: Store the script in a separate module that you import into your program. Provide only the `.pyc` of that module, not the `.py` file. It's not secure but it will discourage casual snooping.

Comment: Even a compiled `.pyd` (or `.so` on Linux) C extension wouldn't prevent the key from appearing somewhere in the binary if not obfuscated somehow, and also then it still wouldn't be secure. But it helps for protection from a simple look.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to protect this key, then you need to treat it as a password.

There are various ways of doing this:

[Securely storing passwords for use in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042724/securely-storing-passwords-for-use-in-python-script) has 3 answers:

- use `bcrypt`
- use `pbkdf2`
- and some homebrew method

[I need to securely store a username and password in Python, what are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options) has 7 answers:

- homebrew RAM only method
- use `keyring`
- use `cryptography`
- use `pbkdf2`
- and 3 more homebrew methods