# Where do i store the passwords in AWS sandbox for a user which i will use for connecting to snowflake via python script

Tags: python, linux, windows, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where in i want to run a python script from a Linux server (AWS sandbox), the purpose of the script is to connect to snowflake database and do some stuff, for connecting to snowflake via a python script i do not want to hard code the password in the script and want the script to get the password from a restricted file.

i know how i did it in windows - i used the credentials manager to store the password and the scripts gets the password from there, i am looking for a similar kind of solution for Linux.

Comment: [possible duplicate] Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12042724/3187537

There are lot of different options.

Answer (score 0):

> connecting to snowflake via a python script i do not want to hard code
>   the password in the script

Instead of storing passwords, you can use key pair authentication:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-key-pair-authentication

Comment: Thanks @gokhan - will try this

Comment: Hi Gokan, i tried this solution and generated the keys.. not sure how do i use it, when i use the passphrase in connection , do i need to type the passphrase or i need to save it in env variable ?

Comment: You need to store the keys in a file, and you also update rsa_public_key for your user. Could you check the sample source code in that page?

Comment: i did that gokan, used the code mentioned in the docs. also updated it with the path of the file and the username account everything, stored the PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE in an environment variable. i am getting the error as ProgrammingError: 251006: Password is empty