# How to secure a username and password in the python module?

Tags: python, security, python-2.7, python-3.x, password-protection

I have a Python script which requires a username and password to log into a specific website. I have stored the username and password in a config.py python module.

But anyone can open this config.py file on a text editor and can view the username and password. This is a huge security issue! How do I prevent this?

I want to encode it using a 64base encoder but it can easily be decoded as well.

**config.py**

```
username='joe'
password='bestpassword'
```

Comment: You can't - however you encrypt it, you will also need to provide the code with a means of decrypting it, which a malicious attacker can use to do so.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I encrypt it?

Comment: **See also**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157938