# writing a variable to a text file and encrypting it?

Tags: python, security, encryption, save, python-3.4

i know how to save a users input to a text file but how do i encrypt it? here is what i have for saving a users input to text file. i tried `f.encrypt("Passwords_log.txt"` but had no results

```
import time
password1 = input("Please type a password: ")
print("Your password has passed the verification!")
time.sleep(1)
print("Saving and encrypting password...")
time.sleep(2)
f=open("Passwords_log.txt",'a')
f.write(password)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
print("Done!")
```

Comment: Where did you see `file.encrypt`? :) You can read more about [File objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) in the Python docs.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the password and save it to the file, or save the password to the file, and then encrypt the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some Python packages worth checking out that deal with cryptography.

[Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/)

[PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/)

A simple example from `cryptography` would be the following:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(b"A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")
plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get some sort of a hash for the password, but file objects have nothing to do with that. You may try to use `base64` encoding (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157938/hiding-a-password-in-a-python-script)), or any other other algorithm of the kind.

Your code:

```
import time
import base64
password1 = raw_input("Please type a password: ")
print("Your password has passed the verification!")
time.sleep(1)
print("Saving and encrypting password...")
time.sleep(2)
f=open("Passwords_log.txt",'a')
password = base64.b64encode(password)
f.write(password)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [password hashing](https://gist.github.com/tqbf/be58d2d39690c3b366ad).

then i'd suggest you use https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/ or pycrypto; depending on what alorithm you choose.

this is just to store the encrypted password. to then encrypt data have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto/2.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

You said, you tried `base64` but it didn't work. Here is how you can make it work:

```
import base64
import time
password1 = input("Please type a password: ")
print("Your password has passed the verification!")
time.sleep(1)
print("Saving and encrypting password...")
time.sleep(2)
f=open("Passwords_log.txt",'a')
cr = base64.encodestring(password1)
f.write(cr)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
print("Done!")
```

This is not real encryption, I wouldn't recommend it for passwords, but since you said in your comment that you tried to use `base64` and it didn't work, I thought I should show you how to use `base64` in your code.

Comment: Just like @Joe R said, Python might not be the best choice for encryption.
See this answer from crypto.stackexchange for more details.
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19969